# tmux script to launch several commands

Tags: scripting, tmux

How can I write the following in a bash script?

```
tmux # Start tmux session.
compass watch /path/to/project1/compass/ # Run the first process.
Ctrl + B, " # Split the pane.
compass watch /path/to/project2/compass/ # Run the second process.
Ctrl + B, D # Exit the session.
```

Answer (score 43):

```
tmux \
    new-session  'compass watch /path/to/project1/compass/' \; \
    split-window 'compass watch /path/to/project2/compass/' \; \
    detach-client
```

The `new-session` command (which creates a new `tmux` session) and the `split-window` command (which splits the current window into two panes) in `tmux` takes optional shell commands to run. The `detach-client` does the obvious at the end.

If you want a horizontal split (two panes side by side), use `split-window -h` in the command above.

When sending multiple `tmux` commands to `tmux` you need to separate them by `;`. The `;` needs to be protected from the shell by quoting/escaping it (`';'`, `";"` or `\;`), to stop the shell from interpreting it as the end of the `tmux` command.

I've split the whole thing into separate lines for readability. If you do this in a script (which I recommend), make sure there's nothing after the final `\` on each line.

Reattach to the session with `tmux a`, `tmux attach`, or `tmux attach-session` (these are all equivalent).

The `tmux` session will end once both commands have finished executing.

Answer (score 16):

This didn't work for me ( I was trying to do something like 'ls -la'). What did was:

```
tmux new-session -d bash
tmux split-window -h bash
#sends keys to first and second terminals
tmux send -t 0:0.0 "<my-first-command>" C-m
tmux send -t 0:0.1 "<my-second-command>" C-m
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

This allowed me to run pretty generic stuff and although it looks ugly, it is pretty functional.

Just leaving it here in case other people are looking for the same thing.

Source: https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/4739236

Comment: Inspired by this answer and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409863/531914 : one need not assume session number and can use named sessions. E.g. `tmux new-session -d -s foo; tmux send-keys -t foo.0 'C-c'; tmux send -t foo.0 'ls'; tmux send-keys -t foo.0 'Enter';`. Also possible to extend this with splits or use of other named sessions at leisure.

Answer (score 6):

To run a short command without exiting at the end:

```
tmux \
    new-session  'ls ; bash' \; \
    split-window 'ls ; bash'
```

or

```
tmux \
    new-session  'ls ; bash' \; \
    new-window   'ls ; bash'
```