# Is it possible to send input to a tmux session without connecting to it?

Tags: tmux, input

Is there any command that I can use to send input or commands to a given tmux session / pane without connecting to it?

It's for unattended access,

I've a console application running on a tmux session. I want to restart it when a deploy (using capistrano) is done.

Is it possible?

Basically I want to send:

```
exit
cd ..
cd app
rails console
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This question has a solution on ServerFault:

- [Run command in detached tmux session](https://serverfault.com/questions/339390/run-command-in-detached-tmux-session)

It uses the `send-keys` command, which is documented in the man-pages:

- [General Commands: TMUX(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1)

The following is a "Hello World" example illustrating the use of the `send-keys` command.

- Step 1. Create a detached session:

  ```
  user@host:~$ tmux new -d -s mySession
  ```
- Step 2: Execute a command in the detached session:

  ```
  user@host:$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "echo 'Hello World'" ENTER
  ```
- Step 3: Attach to the session:

  ```
  user@host:$ tmux a -t mySession
  ```

You should see the following text displayed in the Tmux terminal window:

```
user@host:$ echo 'Hello World'
Hello World

user@host:$
```

This demonstrates that the `echo` command was successfully sent and executed inside of the tmux session.

An adaptation of this technique to your commands might look something like the following:

```
user@host:~$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 exit ENTER
user@host:~$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "cd .." ENTER
user@host:~$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "cd app" ENTER
user@host:~$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "rails console" ENTER
```

Comment: what if something is half written in the tmux terminal. How can I clear the terminal before running `tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "echo 'Hello World'" ENTER`

Comment: @blueray I guess you could send "Ctrl + c" to clear the current line: `tmux send-keys C-c`. That would probably work.

Comment: Make sure if you use `sudo` to create your tmux session that you also call send-keys/send with sudo `sudo tmux send ...` otherwise the command doesn't do anything nor throw an error.

Comment: If you call `tmux send-keys` over `ssh`, you'll need to escape spaces twice: once for `ssh`, and another time for `tmux`, like so: `ssh <host> tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 'echo\ hello' ENTER`

Comment: Or, as I just realised, escape the quotes: `ssh <host> tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 \'echo hello\' ENTER`.