# How to reset the current Tmux session?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux

I sometimes experience a state of `tmux`, where `Prefix-c` stops working although `Prefix-` still works for other commands. Also, in this state, key bindings like `bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"` stop working as well.

In this case, reloading `~/.tmux.conf` doesn't resolve the issue, but terminating the current `tmux` session does.

How can I reset the current `tmux` session, like `reset` would terminal the current terminal?

```
tmux -V
tmux 3.2
uname -a
Darwin C02Y13AVJGH6 20.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Thu Apr 22 21:46:47 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I don’t why and how it happens. It just occasionally happens. I’m fine with a solution to just reset tmux without closing the session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered detaching and sending the `reset` command to the tmux session, as outlined [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409861/is-it-possible-to-send-input-to-a-tmux-session-without-connecting-to-it)? This means running `tmux send -t foo.0 reset ENTER`.

I don't know if this would fix your problem. It would be helpful if you were more specific on what you can and can't do.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't it be equivalent to just executing `reset` in the current Tmux session itself?

Comment: Did you not ask for something that would work `like reset would terminal the current terminal?`

Comment: I’m looking for something equivalent of shutting down the Tmux session without actually shutting it down

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue. I was able to get it working again by running `tmux set-option -g prefix C-b`. Not sure if that would work for you as my issue was slightly different, but may be worth a try!